# ODBC for (localdb)\Test not working

Tags: sql-server, odbc

After creating a new SQLLocalDB instance ( `SQLLocalDB create Test` ) and verifying that it works, I am able to login in successfully to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio using the following:

Server Type: Database Engine

Server Name: (localdb)\Test

After creating a user, (`Security | Login | New Login`) with SQL Authentication, I am able to log out and log back in. I also gave this user `securityadmin` permissions.

My issue is when I try to create a 64-bit ODBC connection (System DSN). Using the ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, and using `(localdb)\Test` the SQL Authentication user account and password, it gives the following error:

Attempting Connection ... The system cannot find the file specified

As can be seen, I can manually login using the same credentials to SQL Server Management Studio, but it won't work when trying to configure an ODBC connection.

I have already verified that `Allow remote connections to this server` is checked (though I don't know if that is really necessary since it is local - but did it anyway).

I have tried using different Drivers, different logins, created a new instance, etc.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

[image: Error When Testing Connection]

Comment: Did you try forcing named pipes via `np:(localdb)\Test`?

Comment: Just tried it and that didn't solve the issue - though that was a good suggestion.

Comment: Try connecting by IP address for the server name.  Sometimes that has worked for me.  Failing that I've had my ODBC drivers be corrupt.  You can reinstall them.

Comment: @sniperd I just installed the driver I'm using - so I don't think that is the issue. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was the incorrect version of ODBC Driver. I needed 13.1 and then it worked fine:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339